# How does Groovy register Closure Listener on JButton

Tags: groovy

I'm learning Groovy and I've seen this example:

```
 button = new JButton('Push me!')
 button.actionPerformed = { event ->
     println button.text
 }
```

There is no `actionPerformed` field/method on JButton....

Could someone explain how Closure is being registered by Groovy on `actionPerformed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`JButton` metaclass registers 31 listeners methods (one of them is `actionPerformed`) and whenever you call `button.actionPerformed = { event -> }` Groovy executes a method like `setProperty(object, field, value)` which checks if there is a listener registered with a given field name - if does, it executes registered listener method (`javax.swing.AbstractButton.addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)` in this case).

#### Detailed explanation

Groovy uses MOP (metaobject protocol) for a dynamic runtime environment. It means that Groovy does not call methods directly like in Java, but uses this additional layer instead. It allows changing class behavior at a runtime.

Whenever we try to set a class field/property value like

```
button.actionPerformed = { event -> println "Clicked!" }
```

Groovy calls proper `setProperty` method. In case of a setting a property for class like `JButton`, following `setProperty` method gets called:

https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L2602

```
/**
 * <p>Retrieves a property on the given receiver for the specified arguments. The sender is the class that is requesting the property from the object.
 * The MetaClass will attempt to establish the method to invoke based on the name and arguments provided.
 *
 * <p>The useSuper and fromInsideClass help the Groovy runtime perform optimisations on the call to go directly
 * to the super class if necessary
 *
 * @param sender The java.lang.Class instance that is mutating the property
 * @param object The Object which the property is being set on
 * @param name The name of the property
 * @param newValue The new value of the property to set
 * @param useSuper Whether the call is to a super class property
 * @param fromInsideClass Whether the call was invoked from the inside or the outside of the class.
 */
public void setProperty(Class sender, Object object, String name, Object newValue, boolean useSuper, boolean fromInsideClass) {
    checkInitalised();

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // handling of static
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    boolean isStatic = theClass != Class.class && object instanceof Class;
    if (isStatic && object != theClass) {
        MetaClass mc = registry.getMetaClass((Class) object);
        mc.getProperty(sender, object, name, useSuper, fromInsideClass);
        return;
    }

    // .....

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // listener method
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    boolean ambiguousListener = false;
    if (method == null) {
        method = listeners.get(name);
        ambiguousListener = method == AMBIGUOUS_LISTENER_METHOD;
        if (method != null &&
                !ambiguousListener &&
                newValue instanceof Closure) {
            // let's create a dynamic proxy
            Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    theClass.getClassLoader(),
                    new Class[]{method.getParameterTypes()[0].getTheClass()},
                    new ConvertedClosure((Closure) newValue, name));
            arguments = new Object[]{proxy};
            newValue = proxy;
        } else {
            method = null;
        }
    }

    // ......
}
```

It goes to the block responsible for checking listener methods. Swing related classes register their listener methods so you can add a listener method like:

```
button.actionPerformed = { event -> .... }
```

instead of

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

  }
})
```

And here is the list of all 31 registered listeners:

[image]

Keys are the names of listeners and values are method objects that receives a closure set to a property. Of course it finds a listener method for a key `actionPerformed` - it gets a reference to a method

```
public void javax.swing.AbstractButton.addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)
```

and it passes a closure

```
{ event ->
    println button.text
}
```

to it.

#### When these listeners like `actionPerformed` get registered to a metaclass?

Metaclass object gets initialized whenever you call a class constructor. Groovy in this case calls

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(Object receiver, Object arg1, Object arg2)
```

https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/AbstractCallSite.java#L245

If you follow call stack you will find these two major checkpoints:

- at some point dynamic call constructor method reaches `CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite()` method that creates a metaclass object https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSiteArray.java#L86
- `MetaClassImpl.initialize()` method calls `addProperties()` which sets up metaclass with e.g. listeners https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L3303
- Inside `MetaClassImpl.addProperties()` Groovy lists all listener methods using `BeanInfo` class and registers all found listeners https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/MetaClassImpl.java#L3343

The full call stack to this `MetaClassImpl.addProperties()` method from IntelliJ IDEA debugger window looks like this:

[image]

You can set a breakpoint at any of these lines if you would like to dig even deeper. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You! Do you also know where those listeners are bing registered? So that actionPerformed is being mapped to addActionListener or mouseEntered to MouseListener.

Comment: @MaciejMiklas Updated the answer with explanation on when these listeners are being registered to a metaclass object.